# How do I launch another app from Java on a Mac

Tags: java, macos, swt, exec

The code I wrote that works fine on Windows is not working on the Mac.
The short form I am calling:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec (String ["/Applications/CM Battle for Normandy/CM Battle for Normandy.app" "2vs2 White Manor 072.ema"], null, "/Applications/CM Battle for Normandy/");
```

There is no file association setup with .ema files by the software I am trying to run (it's a game if you are curious)

My code looks like this:

```
    private void launchGameProgram (PBEMGame selectedGame) {
    if (selectedGame == null)
        return; // no work to do

    InstalledProgram program = selectedGame.playedWith ();
    if (program == null)
        return; // no work to do

    try {
        Vector<String> command = new Vector<String> ();
        command.add (program.getExeFile ().getAbsolutePath ());
        if (selectedGame.getLastTurn () != null  &&  selectedGame.getLastTurn ().getTurnFile () != null)  {
            //  Add the turn file name to the command
            command.add (selectedGame.getLastTurn ().getTurnFile ().getName ());
        }
        GUIApplicationPolicy.getLog ().log ("WTII testing: About to launch: " + command.toString () + " from: " + program.getExeFile ().getParentFile ());
        Runtime.getRuntime ().exec (command.toArray (new String[command.size ()]), null, program.getExeFile ().getParentFile ());
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        GUIApplicationPolicy.getLog ().log (exception);
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This produces the following in the log:

```
!Entry: 2013/10/02 23:08:33.017
!Message: WTII testing: About to launch: [/Applications/CM Battle for Normandy/CM Battle for Normandy.app, 2vs2 White Manor 072.ema] from: /Applications/CM Battle for Normandy

!Entry: 2013/10/02 23:08:33.023
!Exception: Cannot run program "/Applications/CM Battle for Normandy/CM Battle for Normandy.app" (in directory "/Applications/CM Battle for Normandy"): error=13, Permission denied
!Stack: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/CM Battle for Normandy/CM Battle for Normandy.app" (in directory "/Applications/CM Battle for Normandy"): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
    at com.lesliesoftware.whoseturnisit.WhoseTurnIsIt.launchGameProgram(Unknown Source)
    at com.lesliesoftware.whoseturnisit.WhoseTurnIsIt.access$3100(Unknown Source)
    at com.lesliesoftware.whoseturnisit.WhoseTurnIsIt$LaunchSelectedGameProgram.widgetSelected(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3776)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1367)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1390)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1375)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1187)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3622)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3277)
    at com.lesliesoftware.whoseturnisit.WhoseTurnIsIt.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 14 more
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec (String ["open /Applications/CM Battle for Normandy/CM Battle for Normandy.app" "--args" "2vs2 White Manor 072.ema"], null, "/Applications/CM Battle for Normandy/")
```

**UPDATE:** After discussing with Ian..

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec (String ["open" "/Applications/CM Battle for Normandy/CM Battle for Normandy.app" "--args" "2vs2 White Manor 072.ema"], null, "/Applications/CM Battle for Normandy/")
```

Comment: Interesting what does open do in this context?

Comment: @IanLeslie - `open` is a Mac command for executing applications. Try `open /Applications/CM Battle for Normandy/CM Battle for Normandy.app --args 2vs2 White Manor 072.ema` from the `Terminal` to confirm.

Comment: Also, I have edited my answer to add `--args` in it, which is required to pass arguments to the application.

Comment: I am finally back to this...  That yielded the message:
Cannot run program "open /Applications/CM Battle for Normandy/CM Battle for Normandy.app" (in directory "/Applications/CM Battle for Normandy"): error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: Try adding a trailing slash to the name.  I don't know why, but that is what works for me.

Comment: The example you sent me @GreenAsJade also had single quotes around the path which might help - I'll try both.

Comment: I got it to work.  This answer is almost it.  However the open must be its own separate entry in the command array for it to work.  Something like this:String commands[] = {"open", "/Applications/CM Battle for Normandy/CM
Battle for Normandy.app", "--args", "2vs2 White Manor 072.ema"};
runtime.getRuntime().exec (commands, null, "/Applications/CM Battle
for Normandy/")

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute "CM Battle for Normandy.app" and that's a folder (yeah I know can be misleading with the .app extension). What you want to do is to find a binary in that folder and execute that instead. Usually in that folder there's a Contents folder and in it a MacOS folder and in that folder there should be an executable (probably "CM Battle for Normandy").

You can find it with your terminal or Finder.

So my quess is to change:

```
"/Applications/CM Battle for Normandy/CM Battle for Normandy.app"
```

To

```
"/Applications/CM Battle for Normandy/CM Battle for Normandy.app/Contents/MacOS/CM Battle for Normandy"
```

But it might be slightly different. It does not have end in an extension like on Windows (i.e. .exe or smth) but that's because MacOS is a Unix type system.

Comment: OK that made some headway.  However the app did not start properly - it tried but failed - I think it failed to find some of the libraries it depends on.  I am not sure because I did not get a log from this one.  On windows if I try to launch the game with an incorrect "start in directory" I see similar results.  I am going to try telling it to start in the .app directory and see what that gets me.  As you can probably tell I don't own a Mac so I am doing this through a helpful user.  But it is very slow going.

Comment: I don't think you can do this.   You need to use the osx "open" command - it is what knows how to correctly look into .app/ folders. I don't think osx expects anyone to be poking around inside and finding binaries to run...

Answer (score 0):

Is this running things from command line?  I see a command variable but I don't see any context regarding what it actually is/does.  You may need to add a 'sudo' prefix to whatever command that is (assuming it's in terminal).  I'm just inferring that from the Permissions error.

Also, I see a 'getExeFile.'  Maybe I'm misunderstanding this but why would you be looking for a .exe on MacOS?  Again, I could just be misunderstanding this code.  Anyway, I hope this helps or at least helps you jog your brain.

Comment: Not sure how to answer "is this running from command line".  I don't have a command line going but I am trying to start another app and on Windows those parameters would be the same as used in a command line window.

Comment: getExeFile is a method that I wrote for my own private class that was originally written on Windows.  It never occurred to me that on a mac the executable thingy (for lack of a better word) would be a directory and not an file.  So the name is just an artifact the actual File object that comes back is xxx.exe on windows and xxx.app on a mac.

Comment: @IanLeslie "that executable thingy" is a binary file and there are binary files for applications on Mac as I posted in my answer

Comment: Understood @MateuszDymczyk, I am in the process of following up on your suggestion (along with the open suggestion from @vidit).  What I meant was from an end user's point of view the Mac presents the .app folder as the selectable executable entity.  That is pretty different from any other OS where the executable entity is a file.