# SWT: How to use Program.launch() with arguments on OS X?

Tags: java, macos, swt

I'm in a situation where I need to use the SWT function `Program.launch()` but I also require to use it with arguments. Simply put: How can I achieve this? Is it even possible?

I have tried the "normal Mac way" of doing something like this:

`Program.launch("/Applications/SomeApp.app --args myarg");`

This was unsuccessful, and resulted in nothing happening (not even an error). I suspect this is because `Program.launch()` doesn't run through just a command line, but some other OS-specific method. Doing just `Program.launch("/Applications/SomeApp.app");` works fine, but obviously lacks the arguments.

My situation is more explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610422/os-x-java-app-bundle-cannot-open-other-apps) about Java .apps that can open other .apps. In there I explain how using `open` doesn't work, so I'm left with having to use alternatives, where `Program.launch()` seems like a good option.

So basically, is there a way to apply program arguments using `Program.launch()`?

Most similar topics I've read end up with the user migrating to another option, like `open`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Program.launch` just accepts a file name or a URL.

Depending on the protocol of the URL there might be support for specifying arguments as part of the URL, the documentation of the URL format would tell you that.

Comment: I am able to use arguments with this through a URL protocol like `steam://`. But can the same be done for a local app? `file://` doesn't support it from what I've read. It runs the app but also ignores arguments.

Comment: `file` URLs don't support arguments.

Comment: So since it only accepts a file name (regarding local files), it cannot use arguments at all? I guess I will have to look for another method.